# How to write geocode results to csv

Tags: python, geocode

I am trying to use the geocode module and I can't figure out how to write my results to a file.  Below is what I have so far.

How do I write the outputs of that geocode process to the output.csv?

```
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"] = "api_key_from_google_cloud_platform"


import csv
import sys
import geocoder

output = '/Users/Username/Documents/Folder/output.csv'

def main(args):
    with open(args, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data = [row['AddressLine1'], row['City'], row['State'], row['PostalCode'], row['CountryName']]
            separator = ', '
            joined_address = separator.join(data)
            print(joined_address)

            # Open the output file
            with open(output, 'w') as out:
                writer = csv.writer(out, lineterminator='\n')


            # Geocode them
            g = geocoder.google(joined_address)
            g.housenumber
            g.postal
            g.street
            g.street_long

            # Some kind of writer to my output file goes here?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: You already have the CSV writer. Why don't you use it? Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?

Comment: Note that you create a new writer for each input row. The code for writing should probably be outside of the `for row in reader` loop.

Comment: ah good point -- thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (assuming you want the first row to be labels).

```
writer.writerow(["house_number", "postal", "street", "street_long"])
writer.writerow([g.housenumber, g.postal, g.street, g.street_long])
```

Hope this helps!